# Comentarios Condicionais IE7 não funciona

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Tenho um código *HTML*, um com uma condicional para aparecer apenas no IE7   e abaixo coloquei outro código sem condicionais para aparecer no IE8 pra cima e nos outros browsers, mas quando eu abro o IE7 o navegador esta puxando o outro código sem a condicional. Alguém sabe uma solução?

```
<!--[if IE 7]> 
HTML todo
<![endif]-->

Aqui viria outro *HTML* sem condicional
```

Comment: Aqui no IE7 que tenho instalado funcionou normalmente.

Comment: qual IE vc esta usando? como vc fez o IF?

Comment: o IE7 como eu disse, pelo que entendi você quer um "ELSE" para o condicional?

Comment: isso, se for IE7 vai aparecer o que está no comentário condicional de for superior outro navegador aparecer o código abaixo que não está em condicional

Comment: Se eu fosse religioso eu rezaria pra que a espiritualidade tivesse pena da sua alma só pelo fato de você ter que dar suporte ao IE7 (a MS já tá no 11...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi o que disse você quer uma especie de `ELSE` para a condição, poderia fazer isto `if !(IE 7)`, por exemplo:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<p>Você esta usando Internet Explorer 7!</p>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !(IE 7)]>
<p>Você esta usando outro navegador!</p>
<![endif]-->
```

No entanto recomendo repensar o uso disto, porque os comentários condicionais não funcionam em navegadores modernos como dito pela página https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx, **não** há mais suporte a partir do Internet Explorer 10, no entanto é possivel fazer funcionar emulando o IE9 por exemplo, basta adicionar isto:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

Então recomendo rever tudo isto e abandonar estes tipos de *hacks* talvez até criar algo mais simples que ainda sim atenda as funcionalidades esperadas e que se comporte de maneira igual em diversos navegadores, sei que depende de experiencia, mas esta é a oportunidade para se aprimorar, pois dar suporte para duas coisas diferentes pode lhe trazer tantas dores de cabeça quanto tentar criar algo simples que rode em tudo.

Comment: isso eu fiz, em vez do IE7 pegar esse <!--[if IE 7]>
<p>Você esta usando Internet Explorer 7!</p>
<![endif]-->

está pegando o outro aqui no navegador... além disso não aparece nada no ie10, edge e chrome

Comment: @RafaelCastro você por acaso tem alguma tag com `X-UA-Compatible` ou ativou acidetalmente o "modo de compatibilidade" no IE?

Comment: estou usando a emulação do edge para testar e não estou usando a tag X-UA-Compatible

Comment: @RafaelCastro a emulação pode ter algum BUG o meu IE10 tinha este BUG eu fiz o update no windowsupdate e resolveu. Todavia recomendo rever o uso de "Comentarios Condicionais"

Comment: Vou dar uma atualizada aqui e colocar a tag, obrigado

Comment: @RafaelCastro baixa o IETester: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage pra poder emular o IE6/7/8/9/10